# $state.go not working while testing resolve in ui-router

Tags: angular-ui-router, karma-jasmine

$state.go isn't transitioning to default.settings.customization but instead its going to our 'main frontpage'  default.feed

I think it has to do with the resolve, since when I change var state to a different state, it works just fine.

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', function($stateProvider) {
  $stateProvider
.state('default.settings.customization', {
  url: '/settings/customization',
  templateUrl: 'app/settings/customization/customization.html',
  controller: 'CustomizationCtrl',
  auth: {
    authorizedRoles: ['admin']
  },
  resolve: {
    customization: [
      'CustomizationService',
      function(CustomizationService) {
        return CustomizationService.get().then(function(res) {
          return res.data;
        });
      }
    ]
  }
});
}]);
```

Test:

```
var state = 'default.settings.customization';

it('should resolve data', function() {
  customizationServiceMock.get = jasmine.createSpy('customizationServiceMockGet')
    .and.returnValue(apiResp.accountCustomization);
  $state.go(state);
  $rootScope.$apply();
  expect($state.current.name).toBe(state);
});
```

LOG:

```
PhantomJS 1.9.8 (Linux) app/settings/customization router should resolve data FAILED
Expected 'default.feed' to be 'default.settings.customization'.
Error: Expected 'default.feed' to be 'default.settings.customization'.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's related to your spy function, check that apiResp is available in your scope. I had a similary problem, I used $q to return a promise in my spy function but $q was not injected.